# How does NSrange work here?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsrange

I watched a video about ios7 programming and saw piece of codes below.

I can not really understand how the variable range works here.

We create a NSrange variable range and never give it a value, so I think the &range pointer should return nil.

Then how can it be used in effectiveRange and what is the value in range.location and range.length?

Thank you so much for help!

```
- (NSMutableAttributedString *)charactersWithAttribute:(NSString *)attributeName
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *characters = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];

    int index = 0;

    while(index < self.textToAnalyze.length)
    {
        NSRange range;
        id value = [self.textToAnalyze attribute:attributeName atIndex:index      effectiveRange:&range];
        if(value)
        {
            [characters appendAttributedString: [self.textToAnalyze  attributedSubstringFromRange:range]];
            index = range.location+range.length;
        }
        else{
            index++;
        }
    }

    return characters;
}
```

Comment: Look at the code for `attribute:atIndex:effectiveRange:`. Notice what it does with the passed in `NSRange` pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring `NSRange range` allocates memory on the stack (in the local scope). This memory is tied to a memory address that is accessed by `&range`. When you pass this memory address into the method, the method uses the address as the location to which it assigns values. After the method returns, the memory associated with `range` will now have been assigned values so when you access them (to send them to `attributedSubstringFromRange:`), everything will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

NSRange is not an object it us a strict so declaring it sets it up with default values. It doesn't return nil when you declare it.